# Windows 8 push Notification 404 using PHP

Tags: php, windows-8, notifications, wns

I'm sure `access_token` & `sid & secret`is right.

I do not know what will cause 404 Error.

This is my PHP code:

```
public function build_tile_xml($title, $img){
    return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.
    '<toast launch="additionalContextParameters">'.
      '<visual lang="en-US">'.
        '<binding template="ToastImageAndText01">'.
          '<text id="1">'.$title.'</text>'.
        '</binding>'.
      '</visual>'.
    '</toast>';
}

public function post_tile($uri, $xml_data, $type = WPNTypesEnum::Toast, $tileTag = ''){
    if($this->access_token == ''){
        $this->get_access_token();
    }

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/xml', "Content-Length: " . strlen($xml_data), "X-WNS-Type: $type", "Authorization: Bearer $this->access_token");

    if($tileTag != ''){
        array_push($headers, "X-WNS-Tag: $tileTag");
    }

    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    // Tiles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868263.aspx
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close($ch);

    $code = $response['http_code'];

    if($code == 200){
        echo 'Successfully sent message'. "<br>";
        return new WPNResponse('Successfully sent message', $code);
    }
    else if($code == 401){
        echo '$code == 401' . "<br>";
        $this->access_token = '';
        return $this->post_tile($uri, $xml_data);
    }
    else if($code == 410 || $code == 404){
        echo 'Expired or invalid URI ' . $code . "<br>";
        return new WPNResponse('Expired or invalid URI ', $code, true);
    }
    else{
        echo 'Unknown error while sending message ' . $code . "<br>";
        return new WPNResponse('Unknown error while sending message', $code, true);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Obviously your address is incorrect, 404 not found speaks for itself. Add a debug print of the url and try to access it through your browser.

Comment: I resolved.

I found sent string is changed through www

Comment: @eggkouun can u pls explain further how u resolved it

Comment: Url returned during registration contains some urlencoded characters co you have to take extra care so that you do not decode them by mistake